# Uncalled functions in template string

Tags: javascript, template-literals

In the documentation of [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started), I find:

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "palevioletred" : "white"};
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "white" : "palevioletred"}; 
`;
```

I am aware that expressions can be used in tagged template literals, and I read the [docs on template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

When I write my own tagging function (i.e. `styled.button`), I get an array of strings, and some are empty. For example:

```
(x => x)`Hello world ${s => s.toUpperCase()}`
> [ 'Hello world ', '' ]
```

Where is `s` in my example or `props` in their example supplied and when is the function inside the template called?

Answer (score 1):

> Where is s in my example or props in their example supplied [...]

You aren't accepting the rest of the arguments that are passed to your tagged template literal (emphasis mine, via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)):

> Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function. The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string values. **The remaining arguments are related to the expressions.**

A simple implementation using the spread operator to return all arguments as an array:

```
> const myTag = (...args) => args;
> myTag`Hello world ${s => s.toUpperCase()}!`
(2) [Array(2), ƒ]
  0: (2) ['Hello world ', '!', raw: Array(2)]
  1: s => s.toUpperCase()
```

> [...]  and when is the function inside the template called?

Whenever you want to, not implicitly. You get it (and the rest of the templated bits) as additional arguments.